# Determine which process sent message to given process through Binder

Tags: android, android-framework

In android, some app sends a message to systemui app to hide navigation bar, I want to determine which app sent the message..for furthur use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a 3rd party app you cannot see what requested the action through the `Binder`.  It is a 1-to-1 interface between the requesting process and the system framework process (typically system_server.)